# Python sklearn bad input shape

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

i've already check the other solutions for this problem and could not find an answer. I was working on sklearn library with Python, but i have an error that:

> ValueError: bad input shape (1460, 80)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
x,y = data.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1), data['SalePrice']
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(x)
```

How can i solve it? Sorry im kinda newbie on this, thanks for your help

**EDIT1**

Here is the full code of error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "houseai.py", line 11, in
> <module>
>     le.fit(x)   File "C:\Users\UTKU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py",
> line 219, in fit
>     y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)   File "C:\Users\UTKU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
> line 760, in column_or_1d
>     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape)) ValueError: bad input shape (1460, 80)
```

Comment: Can you put the shape of  x & y? You can use x.shape & y.shape for it

Comment: Start by providing some necessary information.  Like the traceback so we know where the error occurs.  If possible identify which input has the wrong shape.  What shape should it have?  You may need to provide the shape of other variables.

Comment: Allright I'll edit now

Comment: As it is said in [LabelEncoder docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit) "array-like of shape (n_samples,)" should be used. You provided dataframe of shape `(1460, 80)` as argument.

Comment: Code that comes *after* the error is never run, irrelevant to the issue, and should *not* be included (just creates unnecessary clutter); same holds for irrelevant imports - just look how more readable and concise the code is now (edited).

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible you have some null values in the data['SalePrice'] or in the floating data, check the null values using

```
bool_series = pd.notnull(data['SalePrice']) 
# displayed data only with team = NaN 
data[bool_series]
```

Check the shape of x and y

```
 x.shape
 y.shape
```

if you still have the same issue then update then sample data